# How can I allow the user to add a value to a dropdown list while editing a form?

Tags: powerapps

I'm creating a form for the end user to edit.  In this form I want there to be dropdown lists that look like this when clicked:

`________________V
Add new item
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3`

If the user were to select "Add new item", is there a way that they would be allowed to add an item to the dropdown selection that can not only be used for the current form but will be saved there for use in future forms? So that in the future, after adding a new item, the dropdown will look like this:

`________________V
Add new item
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4`

I tried adding a custom card to the form and linking the dropdown in that card to a collection.  I was planning on having a text input and collect button become visible when "add item" was selected but this wont be allowed because it "Expected a table value".  Can I add a lookup field to this entity that looks up a value in a collection?

Answer (score 2):

If you save the possible values of the dropdown in a data source (e.g., in a SharePoint list, a SQL table, a CDS entity, etc.) then you can use that data source to populate a local collection, and use that local collection as the source for the dropdown. In this collection you would have two extra values: an empty (the first element in your scenario) and 'Add new item', in addition to the elements that you want to show. For example, if the data source with the options has two columns, Id (type GUID) and Text (type Text), then you can initialize the collection as follows:

```
ClearCollect(myDropdownItems, { Id: Blank(), Text: "" });
Set(IdForAddNewItem, GUID("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"));
Collect(myDropdownItems, { Id: IdForAddNewItem, Text: "Add new item" });
Collect(myDropdownItems, <the data source with the current options>)
```

Now you can set the OnChange property of the dropdown so that if the selected value is 'Add new item', then you would show a dialog / navigate to a different screen where the user can enter the new option. Once the option is saved, you would recreate the collection with the updated data source.

You can take a look at the app from [this link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AonXZuy7S5iZibQfsf-Dr0tbryeZcw). It shows how this can be implemented, but using a local collection instead of a connected data source.